# how to set the Frame of button For iphone 4 and iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios6

I am Develop the iphone application in xcode 4.5 the view size is 320*568 so i set the my button in that view but i run my application in my iphone 4 its screen size is 320*480. so 
    how can i set the button frame for both device in iphone 4 and iphone 5.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the button and frame sets and the orientation support for that Refer the following link.

[Reference link.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

iPhone Rotation, View Resizing and Layout Handling

[Reference link.](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_5_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling)

May this helping to you.